# Select conditionally limited data from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of the form: 
**t_news**

- id
- title
- cat

Categories are not consistent for each news. That is, it may be first 2 news first category, then a third, then a fifth, etc.

> **Need to get to 5 news every category, sorted by date.**

What is the output should be similar to the following (example, 3 news, Category 3)

```
id title  cat
1  News1  1
2  News2  1
3  News3  1
4  News4  2
5  News5  2
6  News6  2
7  News7  3
8  News8  3
9  News9  3
```

Comment: My head hurts trying to comprehend this question. Do you think you could edit it and make what you're asking simpler for idiots like me to understand.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I think the OP wants a query that will return N news items from each category. In SQL Server, I'd do it like `WITH numbered AS (SELECT id,news,cat,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY date desc) as rownum) SELECT id,news,cat FROM numbered where rownum<@n`. Not sure how to do this in MySQL though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can use variables to create a row number column:

```
SELECT  id, title, cat
FROM    (   SELECT  id,
                    title,
                    cat,
                    @r:=IF(@cat = cat, @r+1, 1) AS RowNum , 
                    @cat:= cat AS Cat2 
            FROM    t_news,
                    (SELECT @cat:= 0) AS cat,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) AS r
            ORDER BY cat, id
        ) t
WHERE   RowNum <= 5;
```

The key is at each row if the cat column is the same as the @cat variable (set from the previous row), then the row number increments by one. Otherwise it resets to 0. The order of the increment is set by the order by clause in the subquery (I have used ID since the schema you posted does not include a date column).

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/875fc/5)**

Answer (score 0):

**Total code:**

```
SELECT id, title, cat, from_unixtime(date) `date` FROM (
  SELECT id, title, cat, `date`
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, title, cat, `date`, @r:=IF(@cat = cat, @r+1, 1) AS RowNum , @cat:= category AS Cat2 
    FROM news, (SELECT @cat:= 0) AS cat, (SELECT @r:= 0) AS r
    WHERE hide=0
    ORDER BY cat, `date` DESC, id
  ) t
  WHERE RowNum <= 4 LIMIT 16
) t2 
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

@GarethD, Thank you =)